# Integration Birt parameters with HTML

Tags: html, report, integration, reporting, birt

I working on my Bachelor Thesis and i have a question.
It is possible that Birt will be generate form with parameters on my HTML page from .rptdesign?
I found that i can put the code to my html like [there](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/documentation/integrating/viewer-usage.php)
but this not working.
Maybe somebody know, where i can find examples?

Comment: yes this works. What have you tried and what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the JavaScript or REST API. Check the documentation for examples of using the API with parameters in JSON format.